# Crystal reports charts

Tags: crystal-reports

I am getting my results from my SP as 1.64, 1,76,000, 100 etc along the Y-axis. While displaying the vaues in the report it is rounding off the value 1.64 to 2 and displaying the result. I need to get the exact value, 1.64 to be displayed in the chart along the Y-axis.

Please help me in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the object and select Format Object. Then click on Customize Button in the window which you get. Then you can see a dialogue box. Settings for rounding can be adjusted to your needs here.